# ¿Cómo capturar el imei de un dispositivo en Android Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Intento obtener el imei de mi dispositivo de la siguiente manera solo que no funciona, no muetra error solo no hace nada

```
btnIniciar.setOnClickListener OnClickListener@{
        val tel = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return@OnClickListener
        }

        val s1 = tel.deviceId
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
            "" + s1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        searchLogin(edtUsuario.text.toString(), edtContraseña.text.toString(), s1)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el Imei desde kotlin basta con estas 2 lineas:

```
    val tel = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val IMEI = tel.getImei()
```

No debes olvidar que para acceder a estas propiedades del dispositivo es necesario que declares en `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Y realizar tu respectiva [solicitud de permisos](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419).